# Attempting to remove characters from a string

Tags: java

I am attempting to remove vowels from a randomly generated 20 letter word. I have to use substring for this assignment but am having issues with it conceptually.  With this code, the value of word never changes and stays its original value.  When I do i+2 for the second half of the string it jumps two characters and messes up when there are two vowels directly after one another.  If I have to use substring how can I improve this to work every time.

```
public class WordsWithoutVowels {
    String finalWord;

    public WordsWithoutVowels(String word) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'a') {word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);} 
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'e') {word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);} 
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'i') {word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);} 
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'o') {word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);} 
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'u') {word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);} 
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'y') {word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);}        
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        finalWord = word;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return finalWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you remove a letter from the word, it also just got 1 letter shorter. As a hint, looping backwards can make life a lot easier :)

Comment: so for "matthew", you need "mtthw" as result.

Comment: @Fildor this is the constructor. It does compile

Comment: @yunandtidus Ah, missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the simplified code as below to do so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringPara = "this example will remove the vowals aeiou";
        stringPara = removeCharFromString(stringPara, "a");
        stringPara = removeCharFromString(stringPara, "e");
        stringPara = removeCharFromString(stringPara, "i");
        stringPara = removeCharFromString(stringPara, "o");
        stringPara = removeCharFromString(stringPara, "u");
        System.out.println(stringPara);
    }

    public static String removeCharFromString(String str, String characterToRemove){
        while(str.contains(characterToRemove)){
            str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(characterToRemove)) + str.substring(str.indexOf(characterToRemove)+1, str.length()) ;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: "Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or **beginIndex is larger than endIndex**."

Comment: I don't think so... this is working example, will be executed only when str.contains the character. and there will be no point where beginIndex larger than endIndex

Comment: What if string's last char is a vowel?

Comment: because `indexOf()+1` could not be larger than `str.length` in any case if string contains only 1 character to be removed. as index starts from 0

Comment: Ah, they'd be equal ... sorry. Forget it. Before first coffee here ;)

Comment: No problem. ;) just had my first here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use a simple Regex?

```
String str = "Hello world!";
str = str.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "");
```

The new value of `str` will be `Hll wrld!`

Comment: OP states substring only.

Comment: Alternative answer is bad?

Comment: Quoting the question: *"I have to use substring for this assignment but am having issues with it conceptually."* - whilst this answer works, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: But it may still be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your original solution. First of all - iterate over each letters - to word.length(). Other problem was with increasing "i".

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ) {
  if (word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
    word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1);
    continue;
  }
  if (word.charAt(i) == 'e') {
    word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1);
    continue;
  }
  if (word.charAt(i) == 'i') {
    word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1);
    continue;
  }
  if (word.charAt(i) == 'o') {
    word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1);
    continue;
  }
  if (word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
    word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1);
    continue;
  }
  if (word.charAt(i) == 'y') {
    word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1);
    continue;
  }
  i++;
  System.out.println(word);
}
finalWord = word;
```

Here more elegant way:

```
public class WordsWithoutVowels {

  String finalWord;
  List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y');


  public WordsWithoutVowels(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ) {
      if (vowels.contains(word.charAt(i))) {
        word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
        continue;
      }
      i++;
      System.out.println(word);
    }
    finalWord = word;
  }


  public String getWord() {
    return finalWord;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `i++` operator. It messes up both your character checking as well as your loop. The post decrement operator (`i++`) takes the original value of `i` as method argument but increases its value by one for all subsequent instructions.

To illustrate this, let's assume the input is "Treyarch". Then, at index 2 the character at `i` is `e`. And the instruction
`word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i++);` will have the following consequences:

`word = Treyarch`

`i = 3`

Not only does it not expel the vowel from the `String` it also messes up your index (`i`) . Because for the rest of the loop the `i` is 4 and when you enter the next iteration it will be 5, so your program never checks the first two `if` condition.

That being explained, the best practice for this solution would be to check for any of the conditions in one if statement and use immutable index. In other words:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if(word.charAt(i) == 'a' || word.charAt(i) == 'e' || word.charAt(i) == 'i' || word.charAt(i) == 'o' || word.charAt(i) == 'u' || word.charAt(i) == 'y') {
        word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a problem with your incrementation logic. When you remove a char, you missed the following one.

Your code could be easier to read if you use switch statements.

```
  public class WordsWithoutVowels {
        String finalWord;

        public WordsWithoutVowels(String word) {
            // don't go too far !!
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                switch (word.charAt(i)) {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'o':
                    case 'u':
                    case 'y':
                        // remove this vowel
                        word = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
                        // step back in order to analyse the new i-th char
                        i--;

                }
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            finalWord = word;
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return finalWord;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 String WordsWithoutVowels ="mayank";
 String updated="";
 for(char char1: WordsWithoutVowels.toCharArray())
 {
 switch(char1)
 {
     case 'a':
     case 'e':
     case 'i':
     case 'o':
     case 'u':
         break;
     default:
         updated+=char1;

 }
 }
    System.out.println(updated);
}
```

Comment: OP stated he must use "substring" - it's an assignment.

Comment: Without the substring assignment, This is the most efficicient way of doing it.

Comment: This is not efficient, on the contrary - its horrible in terms of performance and garbage creation. It *would* be efficient if you used a StringBuilder instead of a String for the "updated".

Comment: Yes, you are right that i should use StringBuilder instead of String. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simplified your solution to meet the requirement.

```
public class WordsWithoutVowels {
    String finalWord;

    public WordsWithoutVowels(String word) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);

        for(int i = 0; i < sb.length;) {
            if(sb.charAt(i)=='a' || sb.charAt(i)=='e' || sb.charAt(i)=='i' || sb.charAt(i)=='o' || sb.charAt(i)=='u')
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            else
                i++;
            }
        finalWord = sb.toString();
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return finalWord;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public WordsWithoutVowels(String word) {         
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
          {
    if (word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
        word = word.substring(0, i) + (i == 19 ? "" : word.substring(++i));             } else if (word.charAt(i) == 'e') {
                word = word.substring(0, i) + (i == 19 ? "" : word.substring(++i));             } else if (word.charAt(i) == 'i') {
                word = word.substring(0, i) + (i == 19 ? "" : word.substring(++i));             } else if (word.charAt(i) == 'o') {
                word = word.substring(0, i) + (i == 19 ? "" : word.substring(++i));             } else if (word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                word = word.substring(0, i) + (i == 19 ? "" : word.substring(++i));             } if (word.charAt(i) == 'y') {
                word = word.substring(0, i) + (i == 19 ? "" : word.substring(++i));             }           System.out.println(word + " " + i);
        }       finalWord = word;   }
```